# Incremental Static Regeneration Nextjs 13 without API call

Tags: next.js, static-generator, incremental-static-regeneration

I want to be able to use Incremental static regeneration when calling an endpoint in my Nexjs 13 app. The problem is that my endpoint is an Edge function so I get the following error when building my code:

[image]

This error is displayed when I try to call my Edge function like this in the `app/` directory.

```js
async function fetchPosts() {
  const res = await fetch(`${basePath}/api/myExpensiveEndpoint`, { next: { revalidate: 60 } });
  const data = await res.json();

  return data.posts;
}
```

I think this is expected because its a Nextjs Edge function and they are not allow to be called in Static Generation methods. The solution should be calling the method directly instead of the API. Something like this:

```js
import { myExpensiveFunction } from '../../lib/functions'

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await myExpensiveFunction()

  return {
    props: { posts: data.posts },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}
```

But Nexjs13 does not support `getStaticProps` in the new `app/` directory so that would not work. So I was trying to look for a work around this without using the old `pages/` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { fetchExpensiveCalculation } from '../../lib/expensiveCalculation'

export const revalidate = 3600;

async function ExampleComponent () {
  const schedule = await fetchExpensiveCalculation()
}
```

Calling my function and exporting the constant `revalidate` did the trick :)

Here is the source: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching#segment-cache-configuration